# Problems dowloading iphone-user-guide-for-ios-10

Tags: itunes, books

I recently upgraded my iPhone5, and want to download the iphone-user-guide-for-ios-10.

I found in iTunes on my MacBook Pro running 10.12, and it shows "Downloading", but has been doing this for hours. It is only 23MB.

There seems to be no progress report.

I also tried iBooks (which I use, but have never used the iBooks Store), and clicking on `iBooks Store` does absolutely nothing.

How should I be getting the User Guide?

EDIT:-

---

I successfully downloaded on my iPad, but could not transfer to the Mac.

I booted up an old MacBook running 10.7.5 and iTunes informed me I had already "purchased" this, but let me download a copy. Of course I could not open it on the old Mac, so I copied to the MacBook Pro running 10.12, and could open in iBooks.

I would still like to fix the problem, so I don't have to go through this rigmarole.

Comment: I just downloaded the (23 MB on disk) `iPhone User Guide for iOS 10.epub` file via iTunes and it can down in no time al all, less then a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I don't have a problem.

The `iBooks Store` button in `iBooks` does **nothing**, apparently I should purchase Books through `iTunes`!

**EXCEPT** for User Guides - These can be accessed through the `iTunes` Help menu.

The download of the Guide I found on iTunes apparently does nothing, because they have already been downloaded!! - even though it says downloading for hours!

> Thank You Apple for such a simple, obvious, well documented, easy to use application.